# Reading in an array and multiple scalars at one with @_ with Perl

Tags: perl, variables, subroutine

I am trying to pass some arguments into a sub routine

```
sub mean 
{
my (@values, $chan1, $chan2, $chan3, $chan4) = @_;
print   $chan1, $chan2, $chan3, $chan4;
my $ave_value = sum($values[$chan1],$values[$chan2],$values[$chan3],$values[$chan4])/@values;
}
```

with a call of

```
 push (@avg_value , mean(@datachunk,$subchannel[0],$subchannel[1],$subchannel[2],$subchannel[3]));
```

I am getting error uninitialized value in an array element. I am assuming it because of the way I Am trying read in values. Is this the proper approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array assignment is eating up all the parameters.

For example, in the following, `$foo` and `$bar` will always be undefined, and `@array` will contain 4 elements:

```
my (@array, $foo, $bar) = (1,2,3,4);
```

Here are two potential solutions:

1)  Put scalars first, and then your array:

```
sub mean  {
    my ($chan1, $chan2, $chan3, $chan4, @values) = @_;
    print   $chan1, $chan2, $chan3, $chan4;
    my $ave_value = sum(@values[$chan1, $chan2, $chan3, $chan4])/@values;
}

# Calling method:
mean($subchannel[0], $subchannel[1], $subchannel[2], $subchannel[3], @datachunk)
```

2) Alternatively, you can pass the array by reference:

```
sub mean  {
    my ($arrayref, $chan1, $chan2, $chan3, $chan4) = @_;
    print   $chan1, $chan2, $chan3, $chan4;
    my $ave_value = sum(@{$arrayref}[$chan1, $chan2, $chan3, $chan4]) / @$arrayref;
}

# Calling method:
mean(\@datachunk, $subchannel[0], $subchannel[1], $subchannel[2], $subchannel[3])
```

However, the tightest solution is to restyle your code.  All you want is the average of a list.  Therefore, just pass a list directly instead of the array with index values.

```
sub mean  {
    return @_ ? sum(@_) / @_ : die "Mean of 0 numbers is undefined";
}

# Calling method:
mean(@datachunk[@subchannel[0..3]])
```

Comment: `undef` makes more sense than zero when finding the mean of nothing. Dying even more so.

Comment: Given the OP is pushing means into an array, I'd probably lean toward using `()`.  However, what is important is that he just deal with it in some intentional way that he chooses.  Including an explicit die in the example code communicates that best.

Comment: I disagree with returning an empty list from a function expected to return a scalar. It causes things to fail badly sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Perl isn't as clever as Ruby, so when you gather the parameters to `mean` with the assignment

```
my (@values, $chan1, $chan2, $chan3, $chan4) = @_;
```

you assign the *whole* of `@_` to `@values` leaving `$chan1`, `$chan2` etc. set to `undef`

In general, and especially if you are combining array parameters with scalars, you should pass arrays by *reference*. So your subroutine could be

```
sub mean {
  my ($values, $chan1, $chan2, $chan3, $chan4) = @_;
  print "$chan1, $chan2, $chan3, $chan4\n";
  my $avg = sum(
    $values->[$chan1],
    $values->[$chan2],
    $values->[$chan3],
    $values->[$chan4]
  ) / @values;
}
```

and you would call it as

```
push(@avg_value, mean(
  \@datachunk,
  $subchannel[0], $subchannel[1], $subchannel[2], $subchannel[3]
));
```

However, your `mean` subroutine would be much more generally useful if you passed just the list of values. For instance, if you had `mean` defined as

```
sub mean { sum(@_) / @_ }
```

then you could call it using an array slice, like this

```
push(@avg_value, mean(@datachunk[@subchannel[0..3]]));
```

or, if that is too much for you then split out the slices

```
my @chunk_indices = @subchannel[0..3];
my @values = @datachunk[@chunk_indices];
push @avg_value, mean(@values));
```

I hope this helps